# Can ng-disabled disable group of child elements?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to disable a group of element using ng-disabled in its parent element. Doesn't seem to work.
Does it mean I have to using same condition in all child element to disable ?

I am not able to disable all elements by putting ng-disabled="true" with ul or li element. It works only when I put at input element. Is this how it works ? Also ng-disabled="true" doesn't work with lable or span !

```
<ul style="list-style:none">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" ng-model="color" value="red">
        <label for="radio1" class=""><span>Red</span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" ng-model="color" value="green">
        <label for="radio2" class=""><span>Green</span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" ng-model="color" value="blue">
        <label for="radio3" class=""><span>Blue</span></label>
    </li>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/chiranjib_halder1/pqvz9veu/3/

Comment: if you are trying to just modify the style of your elements you should use something like ng-class="{disable:boolInTheScope}" and then define the style for disabled elements

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Yeah , I should use ng-class to show elements in grey and to disabled the input type I will use ng-disabled.

Comment: group your buttons under <fieldset>, ng-disabled can be used on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-disabled is used on input elements only. here, "checked" is used to enable the button after the checkbox has been checked. here is a hypothetic example:

```
Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Answer (score 2):

You can use this directive:
https://github.com/pleerock/angular-disable-all.git
that basicaly picks the elements inside the directive and disable them.

here is your fiddle code using this directive:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pleerock/angular-disable-all/master/dist/angular-disable-all.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="radioExample">
   <script>
   angular.module('radioExample', ['disableAll'])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.color = 'blue';
       $scope.specialValue = {
         "id": "12345",
         "value": "green"
       };
     }]);
 </script>
 <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isDisabled">Disable all<br>
  <ul style="list-style:none" disable-all="isDisabled">
   <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radio1" ng-model="color" value="red">
      <label for="radio1" class=""><span>Red</span></label>
     </li>
   <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radio2" ng-model="color" value="green">
      <label for="radio2" class=""><span>Green</span></label>
     </li>
   <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radio3" ng-model="color" value="blue">
      <label for="radio3" class=""><span>Blue</span></label>
     </li>
       <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
   <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
   </ul>
  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just a note I couldn't get this to work in conjunction with an ng-include, but otherwise seems very cool.